# how to random set questions in quiz python 3.10.4 tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I make a millionaires in tkinter but i dont know how i can add random set questions. I want add random because the same quiz can get boring and when I do something, I do it exactly.
I mean adding e.g. 'Question 1' as 2, then dest1 as 1 and so on and make it random

I tried to make a list of questions but I couldn't add 'def' there and even if it would be very chaotic and it would be difficult to add a graphical interface, but I have no other idea how to do it
I removed the less important code responsible for, among others, music or photos
This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import pygame
pygame.init()
#okno
okno: Tk = Tk()
okno.geometry('700x850')
okno.title('Poziom Łatwy')
def pytanie1():

    label1 = Label(okno, text="Kto wybił klan Uchiha?", font=30 )
    label1.config(font=(30, 43, 'bold'))
    label1.pack()

    button2 = Button(okno, text='Nagato', font=30, command=dest1p)
    button2.place(x=425, y=500)
    button2.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    button1 = Button(okno, text='Itachi', font=30,command=dest1p )
    button1.place(x=47, y=500)
    button1.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    button3= Button(okno,text='Shisui' ,font=30,command=dest1p)
    button3.place(x=40,y=660)
    button3.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    button4 = Button(okno, text='Madara', font=30,command=dest1p)
    button4.place(x=420,y=660)
    button4.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

def dest1p():

    labelq1 = Label(okno, text="Ile było ogoniastych bestii?", font=30)
    labelq1.config(font=(30, 40, 'bold'))
    labelq1.pack()

    buttonq2 = Button(okno, text='8', font=30,command = dest2)
    buttonq2.place(x=525, y=500)
    buttonq2.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    buttonq1 = Button(okno, text='6', font=30,command = dest2)
    buttonq1.place(x=47, y=500)
    buttonq1.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    buttonq3 = Button(okno, text='7', font=30,command = dest2)
    buttonq3.place(x=40, y=660)
    buttonq3.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    buttonq4 = Button(okno, text='9', font=30,command = dest2)
    buttonq4.place(x=520, y=660)
    buttonq4.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))
def dest2():

    labelw1 = Label(okno, text="Kto był liderem drużyny 7?", font=30)
    labelw1.config(font=(30, 40, 'bold'))
    labelw1.pack()

    buttonw2 = Button(okno, text='Hiruzen', font=30)
    buttonw2.place(x=425, y=500)
    buttonw2.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    buttonw1 = Button(okno, text='Minato', font=30)
    buttonw1.place(x=47, y=500)
    buttonw1.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    buttonw3 = Button(okno, text='Kakashi', font=30)
    buttonw3.place(x=40, y=660)
    buttonw3.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))

    buttonw4 = Button(okno, text='Marek', font=30)
    buttonw4.place(x=420, y=660)
    buttonw4.config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))
pytanie1()
okno.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand Polish, so I hope this is what you mean:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
# okno
okno: Tk = Tk()
okno.geometry('700x850')
okno.title('Poziom Łatwy')

questions_list = [
    {'question': "Kto wybił klan Uchiha?", 'answers': ['Nagato', 'Itachi', 'Shisui', 'Madara', ]},
    {'question': "Ile było ogoniastych bestii?", 'answers': ['6', '7', '8', '9', ]},
    {'question': "Kto był liderem drużyny 7?", 'answers': ['Hiruzen', 'Minato', 'Kakashi', 'Marek', ]},
]

random.shuffle(questions_list)


class Questions:
    def __init__(self, questions):
        self.questions = questions
        self.current_question = 0
        self.next_question()

    def next_question(self):
        def make_question(question_dict, action=None):
            for child in okno.winfo_children():
                child.destroy()
            question_frame = Frame(okno).pack()
            label1 = Label(question_frame, text=question_dict['question'], font=30)
            label1.config(font=(30, 43, 'bold'))
            label1.pack()

            random.shuffle(question_dict['answers'])
            buttons = []
            for i, answer in enumerate(question_dict['answers']):
                buttons.append(Button(question_frame, text=answer, font=30, command=action))
                buttons[i].place(x=(i % 2 * 400 + 40), y=(i // 2 * 160 + 500))
                buttons[i].config(font=(30, 41, 'bold'))
        do_something = None
        if self.current_question < len(self.questions) - 1:
            do_something = self.next_question
        make_question(self.questions[self.current_question], do_something)
        self.current_question += 1


q = Questions(questions_list)
okno.mainloop()
```